# Google Play: My application doesn't appear on Android Wear category

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, google-play-developer-api

My company has a handheld application published and in the last release we've added an Android Wear app to it. When the users download and install it, it works on the Android Wear devices too, but it doesn't appear under [Android Wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ANDROID_WEAR) category.

Should I add a flag to it? Is something I missed on Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where it is on the Play dev console. On the **Pricing & Distribution** page, under the country list and **Ads** section.
[image]

A couple of additional notes, though:

- Your app needs to be approved before it'll appear in the category. I've had an app rejected because it didn't deal with a "flat tire" display correctly, for example. I believe this is the [offical list of criteria](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html).
- Like most of the dev console, changes don't go live immediately. They take some time to filter out through the production Play store.